# Return tomorrow's day name

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I would like to return the weekday name of tomorrow (i.e. if today is Sunday, I want Monday). Here's my code that yields today's weekday name.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
weekDay =  [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Rather than messing with NSCalendar, what would be a concise way of doing this (following the code I have here)?

Thank you.

Comment: NSDateComponents has methods that help. Get the day get the next day.

Comment: Well, you could always run the above +24 hours, if you're not too concerned about leap hours, etc.  dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your comment, Abizern. Here's what I did:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    weekDay = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSDateComponents *tomorrowComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSDate *compDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:tomorrowComponents];

    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    offsetComponents.day = 1;
    NSDate *tomorrow = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:compDate options:0];

    nextWeekDay = [formatter stringFromDate:tomorrow];
```

Two NSString objects (weekDay and nextWeekDay) now store the days of the week names for today and tomorrow (currently Sunday and Monday).
This works well, but I wonder if there's an easier way. Objective-C dates are quite cumbersome :(

Thanks again.

Comment: You don't have to add the dates; you can just increment the `day` of today's `NSDateComponents`. Date handling is cumbersome no matter the framework; `NSDateFormatter` and `NSCalendar` already hide a mountain of complexity. If you need this functionality often, put it into a library for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

user's language aware:

```
NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSArray *weekdays = [df weekdaySymbols];

NSDateComponents *c = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
c.day = 1;
NSDate *tomorrow = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:c
                                                                 toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                                options:0];
c = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit
                                    fromDate:tomorrow];

NSString *tomorrowname = weekdays[c.weekday-1];// the value of c.weekday may 
                                               // range from 1 (sunday) to 7 (saturday)    
NSLog(@"%@", tomorrowname);
```

---

if you need to have the name in a certain language, add

```
[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

after the creation of the date formatter.

Comment: yeah, copy and paste error: I took it from a code, where I demonstrated how to get the first n user's languages.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you afraid of "messing" with NSCalendar? For using the NSDateComponents methods, you will actually have to make use of NSCalendar. This is my solution for your problem.

```
// Get the current weekday
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
// !! Sunday = 1
NSInteger weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
```

Now, you can use the NSDateFormatter method *-(NSArray* *)*weekdaySymbols* which contains weekdays starting with Sunday at index 0. As the integer returned by [weekdayComponents weekday] starts with 0 for Saturday, we do *not* have to increase the value stored in weekday:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// !! Sunday = 0
NSUInteger symbolIndex = (weekday < 7) ? weekday : 0;
NSString *weekdaySymbol = [[formatter weekdaySymbols] objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)symbolIndex];
```

I hope this was helpful although using NSCalendar to some extent.

**EDIT:** glektrik's solution is pretty straight ahead. But mind the following statement in the NSDate class reference of *- dateByAddingTimeInterval:*.

> **Return Value:**
>   A new NSDate object that is set to seconds seconds relative to the receiver. The date returned might have a representation different from the receiver’s.

Comment: Yes and no! [formatter weekdaySymbols] returns (Sunday, Monday, ...), consequently, Sunday is to be accessed via index 0 here. And as mentioned above, Sunday is represented as 1 if using [weekdayComponents weekday].